# Errors while running a ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I installed rvm and ruby on rails on a mac. After installing all the bundles, when I ran the rails -s command, I got these errors. Since I am new to ruby on rails, I have no idea what these errors mean and how can I resolve them.

Also added the code of posts_controller_test.erb

```
Running:
E
Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: authors.email: INSERT INTO "authors" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-01-29 11:46:00.853708', '2018-01-29 11:46:00.853708', 298486374)
bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:13
E
Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_show_post:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: authors.email: INSERT INTO "authors" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-01-29 11:46:01.050540', '2018-01-29 11:46:01.050540', 298486374)
bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:26
E
Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: authors.email: INSERT INTO "authors" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-01-29 11:46:01.056155', '2018-01-29 11:46:01.056155', 298486374)
bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:31
E
Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_create_post:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: authors.email: INSERT INTO "authors" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-01-29 11:46:01.062023', '2018-01-29 11:46:01.062023', 298486374)
bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:18
E
Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: authors.email: INSERT INTO "authors" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-01-29 11:46:01.068163', '2018-01-29 11:46:01.068163', 298486374)
bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:8
E
Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_post:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: authors.email: INSERT INTO "authors" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-01-29 11:46:01.073382', '2018-01-29 11:46:01.073382', 298486374)
bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:41
E
Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_update_post:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: authors.email: INSERT INTO "authors" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-01-29 11:46:01.079061', '2018-01-29 11:46:01.079061', 298486374)   
bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:36
Finished in 0.258853s, 27.0424 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
7 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 7 errors, 0 skips
```

posts_controller_test.erb

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @post = posts(:one)
  end

test "should get index" do
 get posts_url
  assert_response :success
end

test "should get new" do
 get new_post_url
  assert_response :success
 end

test "should create post" do
  assert_difference('Post.count') do
  post posts_url, params: { post: { body: @post.body, description: @post.description, slug: @post.slug, title: @post.title } }
  end

  assert_redirected_to post_url(Post.last)
  end

  test "should show post" do
   get post_url(@post)
   assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
  get edit_post_url(@post)
  assert_response :success
  end

   test "should update post" do
   patch post_url(@post), params: { post: { body: @post.body, 
   description: @post.description, slug: @post.slug, title: @post.title 
    } }
   assert_redirected_to post_url(@post)
   end

  test "should destroy post" do
   assert_difference('Post.count', -1) do
  delete post_url(@post)
  end

   assert_redirected_to posts_url
 end
 end
```

Comment: When you start `rails s`, it shouldn't run rails test. Please try `bundle exec rails s -e development`

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOFCa.png

Comment: Now I am getting this error

Comment: do you cleanup the DB before each run?

Answer (score 0):

"Unique Constrain" means you are trying to insert the same value on your `author email` field multiple times, while your database is set to only allow unique values.

Can't tell without the rest of the code, but looks like your tests are either not resetting properly or your are trying to create the same author multiple times.

Try posting the code in the `posts_controller_test.rb` file.